# Windows Forms Chart: Get mouse cursor coordinates in Chart axis scale?

Tags: winforms, charts, onclick, position, coordinates

I have a problem with the following sample:

[image]

When I click at the place marked as **'1'** on my screenshot, I can get position in pixels by MouseClick event in a pretty easy way:

```
private: System::Void chart1_MouseClick(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::MouseEventArgs^  e) {

        Point chartLocationOnForm = chart1->FindForm()->PointToClient(chart1->Parent->PointToScreen(chart1->Location));                

        cursorPosX = e->X - chartLocationOnForm.X;
        cursorPosY =  e->Y - chartLocationOnForm.Y;
}
```

After printing these values out, I get the position in pixels, where position marked as **'2'** is equal to (0,0).

**What I would like to get after clicking the spot in '1' is**

> **X: 40
>
>   Y: 178.5**,

**which are the coordinates inside my chart**. Is there any **civilised** way to do that (I mean other than considering padding, margins and borders of the chart and calculating these coordinates by myself)?

**One of my ideas was to create some sort of invisible CursorX and CursorY and use its methods**, but it still seems to be more like a fancy way to solve simple problem than a real, straight-forward solution. Am I right or this *really* is the way I am supposed to solve my problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, there is a civilized way of doing that if I understand your question correctly. You can use the Axis.PixelPositionToValue method to do just that.

E.g. (in C#)

```
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.PixelPositionToValue(pt.X)
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.PixelPositionToValue(pt.Y)
```